# Learnable weighted sum of tensors

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to implement deep supervision strategy in an encoder-decoder architecture using PyTorch. The idea is to do the weighted sum of the results of three convolution layers (with a learnable parameters `Wi`).

Suppose we have three tensors: `A`, `B` and `C` of identical shapes: `(64, 48, 48, 48)`.

My goal is to do a **weighted linear sum** of these three tensors: `(w0 * A + w1 * B + w2 * C)` with `w0`, `w1`, `w2` should be learnable parameters by the network.

Maybe I have to use `torch.nn.Linear(in_features, out_features)`, but I dont know what will be in and out features in this case.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a custom parameter tensor and store the `w_i` in it. Then compute the weighted sum of the matrices with the weights.

Register the custom parameter like so:

```
W = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(3))
```

You can either compute the sum by hand:

```
w0, w1, w2 = W
res = w0*A + w1*B + w2*B
```

Or instead use [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html) for conciseness. Do note this approach doesn't depend on the number of components in your linear sum:

```
X = torch.stack([A, B, C])
res = torch.einsum('mbchw,m->bcw', X, W)
```

---

Good thing you pointed out [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html), you can actually pull it off with this layer. Notice that `nn.Linear` can take an n-dimensional tensor as input: `(batch_size, *, in_features)` and will output `(batch_size ,*, out_features)`, where `*` **can be any number of dimensions**. In your case `in_features` is the number of weights and `out_features` is `1`. Looking at it differently: you only require *1* neuron to compute the weighted sum. One important thing though is that the "feature" dimension must be last, *i.e.* the stack must be done on the last dimension:

```
W = nn.Linear(3, 1)
res = W(torch.stack([A, B, C], dim=-1))
```

And the output shape will be:

```
>>> res.shape
torch.Size([64, 48, 48, 48, 1])
```